Configure Minio with Spring Boot using Docker
So I am trying to interact between Minio and my Spring Boot backend using Docker.
When i test it without Docker locally i can upload a file to Minio using my Spring boot backend and then generate a URL with which i can access this file later.
Now when i try the same thing with Docker i can upload the video but when i try to access it using my generated URL i get a Signature Does not Match response.
i tried with this application properties in spring boot
spring.application.name=demo

# MinIO configuration
minio.url=http://localhost:9000
minio.access-key=minioadmin
minio.secret-key=minioadmin

# Max file size for a single file
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
# Max request size (for multi-part requests)
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB

and this docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  minio:
    image: quay.io/minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./minio-data:/data
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"

  springboot-app:
    build:
      context: ./demo
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: springboot-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - minio.url=http://minio:9000
      - minio.access-key=minioadmin
      - minio.secret-key=minioadmin
    depends_on:
      - minio

this is the function in spring boot i use to upload the video and create the URL
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadVideo(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam("patientId") String patientId,
            @RequestParam("encounterId") String encounterId) {
        try {
            String bucketName = "videos-bucket";
            String objectName = file.getOriginalFilename();

            // Check if the bucket exists, if not Create it
            if (!minioClient.bucketExists(BucketExistsArgs.builder().bucket(bucketName).build())) {
                minioClient.makeBucket(MakeBucketArgs.builder().bucket(bucketName).build());
            }

            // Upload the video
            InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
            String videoUrl = minioService.uploadVideo(bucketName, objectName, inputStream, file.getSize(), file.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Generated Presigned URL: " + videoUrl);


            String externalVideoUrl = videoUrl.replace("http://minio:9000", "http://172.19.112.1:9000");
            System.out.println("Generated externalVideoUrl : " + externalVideoUrl);

            // Create FHIR client
            IGenericClient client = fhirContext.newRestfulGenericClient(hapiFhirUrl);

            // Create FHIR Media resource
            Media media = new Media();
            media.setStatus(Media.MediaStatus.COMPLETED);
            media.setType(new CodeableConcept().setText("video"));
            media.setContent(new Attachment()
                    .setUrl(externalVideoUrl)
                    .setContentType(file.getContentType()));
            media.setSubject(new Reference("Patient/" + patientId));
            media.setEncounter(new Reference("Encounter/" + encounterId));
            media.setCreated(new DateTimeType(Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));

            MethodOutcome outcome = client.create().resource(media).execute();

            IIdType mediaId = outcome.getId();
            System.out.println("Media ID = " + mediaId.getIdPart());

            // Read the encounter resource
            Encounter encounter = client.read().resource(Encounter.class).withId(encounterId).execute();

            // Add extensions to the encounter resource
            Extension videoUploadedExtension = new Extension("http://example.com/fhir/StructureDefinition/videoUploaded", new BooleanType(true));
            encounter.addExtension(videoUploadedExtension);

            Extension mediaIdExt = new Extension("http://example.com/fhir/StructureDefinition/mediaId", new Reference("Media/" + mediaId.getIdPart()));
            encounter.addExtension(mediaIdExt);

            // Update the encounter status to IN-PROGRESS
            encounter.setStatus(Encounter.EncounterStatus.INPROGRESS);

            // Update the encounter resource
            client.update().resource(encounter).execute();

            return ResponseEntity.ok(fhirContext.newJsonParser().encodeResourceToString(outcome.getResource()));
        } catch (MinioException | IOException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("An unexpected error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

